# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' & functions_main.php on line 1114

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, syntax-error, wordpress-theming

Im installing my Wordpress theme and when I click activate I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in E:\Websites\HostingSpaces\mov1\movies.in\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\wp_mov\functions_main.php on line 1114

Anyone have any idea of how fix it?

Comment: How do i show yee the php file?

Comment: I'm gussing your PHP version is lower than 5.4? The "short array syntax" was introduced in PHP 5.4, so if you are on a lower version I highly recommend you upgrade to a higher version (the alternative is to find a PHP <5.4 compatible WP install of your theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by new-style array initialization ("short array syntax"), [introduced in PHP 5.4](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

```
<?php
$myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

$myAssociativeArray = [
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
];
```

You'll have to upgrade to PHP 5.4 or better. If you let me know what OS you're using, I can provide specific instructions.

More info can be found in the [array type manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: im on a Cloud host. And i dont have cpanel just websitepanel. how would i update the php? are you familiar with websitepanel

Comment: Ah, no, not at all. Contact the web host and let them know you require PHP 5.4+.

Comment: thanks will, ill see how i get on

Comment: No problem, glad to help! You may also look into getting a better website with more modern tools. PHP has improved greatly in the later 5.x releases.

Comment: Hi again will. My host said they dont have php 5.4+ available for cloud host yet, what can i do?